# Systemd scripts will not run on boot

Tags: scripting, docker, systemd

I have three docker containers that I've created systemd scripts to run at startup. I've run `systemctl enable xxxx` for all three services, and i've tried `systemctl reenable xxxx` as well. I've created the scripts from the docker documenation. If I run the scripts with `service xxx start`, the script runs fine. Whenever I reboot, the docker service runs fine, but the three scripts remain loaded but inactive:

```
● guacd.service - Redis container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/guacd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

The composition of my script `/etc/systemd/system/guacd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start -a guacd

ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 guacd

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

Comment: This isn't the right way to go about it to begin with. You should be setting Docker restart policies when you create the containers.

Comment: Which is what I have since done, however that does not explain why this documented feature does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Is it `WantedBy=local.target`? Maybe `WantedBy=local-fs.target`

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#local-fs.target